# sql : combining 2 query to give 1 resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

In a case where I have to perform 2 queries, I wanted to replace it by simply one single line of query. Example:

```
select col1, col2 from tableA where col3 = 'a';
```

This will return (consider) 2 rows:

```
col1    col2

abc     abc.bcd
xyz     xyz.pqr
```

Now, in a second table we made a different query for each rows from query 1:

```
   select col1 from tableB where col2 = 'abc';
   (AND)
   select col1 from tableB where col2 = 'xyz';
```

This will give a result set like:

```
 TableB
 col1    
 1111    
 2222
```

If the question is unclear kindly mention I shall try to elaborate with better example.

(although database vendor is not issue, I am comfortable with oracle or mysql. Thanks).

Comment: @Ranajan Sarma: @Rene's answer seems correct. But I still wonder how can you get both `Col1, Col2` in the result set, even when you are querying only `Col1` in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: @Daredev: You are right. Rene's answer worked perfect and in my second result set col 2 should not appear. I shall do the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select col1 
from tableB
where col2 in (select col1 
               from tableA 
               where col3='a')
```

Comment: That doesn't output 2 columns..?

Comment: I don't think selecting the correct number of columns was the real problem here.

Comment: Fair point, but given that the example final resultset contains TableA.col1, I don't see how a subselect is the right solution.. Surely its a simple join?

Comment: @StevieG: I am not expert in pl/sql or database querying. But in the back end (java) I had to loop for each rows in result 1 and build the result set 2.

Comment: @Ranjan - that means you're running multiple queries. If you do a join (as in my answer and bvbiz's answer) you only need to hit the database once.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just need a join between the two tables like this:

```
SELECT b.col1, a.col1
FROM tablea a 
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.col1 = b.col2
WHERE a.col3 = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single query like :

```
select col1 from tableB where col2 = 'abc' or col2 = 'xyz';
```

And if you have large number of strings to check for then you can use :

```
select col1 from tableB where col2 in ('abc','xyz','mno');
```

Update: you can use nested queries like :

```
select col1 from tableB where col2 in (select col1 from tableA where col3='a');
```

But make sure that data type of `col1` inside that nested query and data type of `col2` after `where` match.

Comment: abc and xyz are the results which are not known before we perform query 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the single query as,

```
select col1, col2 from tableB where col2 = 'abc' or col2='xyz'
```

Comment: How does that help? 'xyz' is a value stored in table A ?

Comment: @StevieG: he was asking only from a single table. and the result he wanted also is from a single table. so, only a single table **tableB** is sufficient

Comment: The result the OP wanted is `TableB.col1, TableA.col1` isn't it? or am I missing something? The title of the question is also 'combining 2 queries to give 1 resultset', so I think he probably wants a join..

Answer (score 0):

It' s not completely clear to me, but I think you are looking for a usual Join expression?

SELECT B.Col1, A.Col1 FROM TableA A inner join TableB B on A.Col1 = B.Col2

Please refer to the Join expression.  This example is for SQL Server and newer versions of Oracle.